# Jmeter JDBC config element options

Tags: sql, jdbc, jmeter

I need a clarification where one of my retrieval type stored procedure when pushed in jmeter for load scenario did not work with 'auto-commit (false) and transaction-isolation(transaction serializable)' options.
But when configuring it as 'auto-commit (true) and transaction-isolation(default)' 
it gives expected results.
Can someone help me understand the logic here though it is a retrieval type stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose autocommit false then your statement won't be committed, meaning an update/insert won't effect the database (unless explicitly write commit; in request).

About transaction-isolation I suggest to keep default value unless you testing the database call itself.

Comment: Hi Thanks. But my doubt is also why it would need a read lock(read committed) for retrieval type stored procedure. Pls correct my understanding.